# Anything like PHPMyAdmin for LDAP?

Tags: phpmyadmin, ldap, openldap

Does anyone know of anything like PHPMyAdmin for LDAP?  I been looking but did not find anything free yet?

Comment: You should take a look at this [list](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20Browsers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page - > PhpLdapAdmin